# Destination 127.0.0.1, 7001 unreachable - Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I installed `weblogic 12.1.2` and changed the port from `7001` to `8081` through console and restarted the server.

However, when I deployed my application and ran it, I am getting the below exception.

I dont understand why the server is trying to access `7001`, when the listner port is `8081`. Can anyone help?

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3://localhost:7001: Destination 127.0.0.1, 7001 unreachable; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; No available router to destination]
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(ExceptionTranslator.java:40)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.toNamingException(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:808)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:363)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:319)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:288)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at doradus.core.logging.general.service.LogBeanController.logRemote(LogBeanController.java:575)
    at doradus.enterprise.logging.business.service.LoggingMDB.onMessage(LoggingMDB.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:103)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:109)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy226.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:575)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:477)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:375)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:4855)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:4529)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.executeMessage(JMSSession.java:3976)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.access$000(JMSSession.java:120)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:5375)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: t3://localhost:7001: Destination 127.0.0.1, 7001 unreachable; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; No available router to destination
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:216)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreate(RJVMFinder.java:169)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ServerURL.findOrCreateRJVM(ServerURL.java:165)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate$1.run(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:342)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:337)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Destination 127.0.0.1, 7001 unreachable; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; No available router to destination
    at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:490)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:328)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreateRemoteInternal(RJVMManager.java:267)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreate(RJVMManager.java:204)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteServer(RJVMFinder.java:238)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:200)
    ... 46 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that your application is accessing some application configuration you have on the server which is still pointing to the 7001 port?

You could look in the **${WL_HOME}/config/config.xml** file to double check that the port has infact changed and then also do a '**netstat -an | grep LISTEN**' (Linux Machine?) to see what is listening on which ports.

Answer (score 1):

When you change port from admin console, changed port gets reflected in **${WL_HOME}/config/config.xml** (atleast in my case it did), but this change is not reflected in start/stop scripts present in **${WL_HOME}/bin** directory. For example:

- setDomainEnv.sh
- startManagedWebLogic.sh
- startWebLogic.sh
- stopManagedWebLogic.sh
- stopWebLogic.sh

still contain old port. You will have to change search and change them manually.